Spring Security Warning: How to Fix AuthenticationProvider vs. UserDetailsService Configuration?
I’m encountering a warning when starting my Spring Boot application with Spring Security configuration. The warning message is:
WARN [  restartedMain] r$InitializeUserDetailsManagerConfigurer : Global AuthenticationManager configured with an AuthenticationProvider bean. UserDetailsService beans will not be used for username/password login. Consider removing the AuthenticationProvider bean. Alternatively, consider using the UserDetailsService in a manually instantiated DaoAuthenticationProvider.

I’ve configured JWT-based authentication in my Spring Boot application. Here are the relevant parts of my configuration:
SecurityFilterChain:
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                        authorize
                                .requestMatchers("/assets/**", "/css/**", "/images/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/", "/about", "/contact").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

Relevant part of ApplicationBeanConfiguration:
@Configuration
public class ApplicationBeanConfiguration {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public ApplicationBeanConfiguration(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }
}

The warning persists regardless of whether I include or exclude the AuthenticationProvider bean. The application starts with the warning, indicating that the AuthenticationProvider configuration might be conflicting with UserDetailsService.
The warning suggests that my setup might be incorrectly configured. Specifically, it indicates that the AuthenticationProvider bean is overriding the UserDetailsService, which could lead to issues with username/password authentication.
How should I correctly configure Spring Security to avoid this warning?

by not building a home made security solution, handing out JWTs to browsers is not recommended, so what is the purpose of the jwtauthenticationfilter. There is a reason such a filter does not exist in spring security

Hi, Hyusein. Please remove the AuthenticationManager and AuthenticationProvider bean publishings. Also please remove the .authenticationProvider call in the DSL. What happens at that point? (Note that my recommendation comes without knowing much of what your jwtAuthenticationFilter does. I'm assuming that bc you said you've removed AuthenticationProvider before that it isn't necessary to the filter.)

@Toerktumlare
I follow this tutorial - [link] (https://medium.com/@tericcabrel/implement-jwt-authentication-in-a-spring-boot-3-application-5839e4fd8fac)

Please do not follow tutorials, read the official documentation

@Toerktumlare What do you imply by home-made security solution instead of sending JWTs to browser/REST client?

Im implying that you are building something you shouldnt https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/password/ the authentication you are building is not one of the predefined ones in the spring security framework, meaning its home made and is not following any of the given security standards. Whats the point of pulling in a security framework when you then decide to not use its features and then build something that is not secure?

You have registered the AuthenticationProvider twice:

By declaring the AuthenticationProvider as @Bean (see your: authenticationProvider() method ApplicationBeanConfiguration class)
And by settng it as .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider) (see your: securityFilterChain method)

that's why the warning
Solution:
Removng @Bean from authenticationProvider method can help to aviod the warning.

In this snippet of your code
Basically, you'll only need a bean of AuthenticationManager then return new Instance of ProviderManager which is one of the implementations of AuthenticationManager. It takes any implementation of AuthenticationProvider(in this case : DaoAuthenticationProvider) in it's constructor.
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
                    return config.getAuthenticationManager();
}
            
@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
return authProvider;
}

Replace The above Snippet with this, it should remove the warning.
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return new ProviderManager(authProvider);
 }


I'm a Spring Security Novice, however, to other folks that come across this question (as I followed a similar tutorial). The key issue is that there is not a need to create an Authentication provider or Manager if you use the Auto-Configuration concepts. (@Jzheaux's comments were correct).
It seems like the main reason for doing that in the tutorial was to register AuthProvider with the PasswordEncoder and the UserDetailService, but spring will pick these up if you define them as beans/services. If you are doing JWT's, the main work is in the JWT Filter despite Toerktumlare's aggressive comments. My working Configuration class below that I use to manage security with JWTs.
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.security.enabled}")
    private boolean securityEnabled;

    private final JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter) {
        this.jwtRequestFilter = jwtRequestFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        if (securityEnabled) {
            http
                    .cors(cors -> cors.disable())
                    .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                            .requestMatchers("/auth", "/error", "/auth/**").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    )
                    .sessionManagement(session -> session
                            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    )
                    .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception
                            .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
                    );
        } else {
            http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().permitAll())
                    .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
        }
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "content-type", "x-auth-token"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("x-auth-token"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}

